# Can mongoimport maintain the specified order of deep nested keys?

Tags: mongodb, nested, mongoimport

I have some test data that I'm trying to import into MongoDB:

```
{ "name": "A3", "year": "1999", "parts": { "oil filter": { "type": 2, "partno": "123" }, "air filter":{ "type": 6, "partno": "gf6" } }}
{ "name": "A3", "year": "2000", "parts": { "oil filter": { "type": 2, "partno": "123" }, "air filter":{ "type": 6, "partno": "gf6" } }}
{ "name": "A3", "year": "2001", "parts": { "oil filter": { "type": 2, "partno": "123" }, "air filter":{ "type": 6, "partno": "gf6" } }}
{ "name": "A3", "year": "2002", "parts": { "oil filter": { "type": 2, "partno": "123" }, "air filter":{ "type": 6, "partno": "gf6" } }}
{ "name": "A3", "year": "2003", "parts": { "oil filter": { "type": 2, "partno": "557" }, "air filter":{ "type": 6, "partno": "gf4" } }}
{ "name": "A3", "year": "2004", "parts": { "oil filter": { "type": 2, "partno": "557" }, "air filter":{ "type": 6, "partno": "gf4" } }}
```

If I insert the lines using db.cars.insert(), all nested fields appear exactly in the order shown. However, if I import these lines using **mongoimport**, the order gets messed up:

```
{ "name" : "A3", "year" : "1999", "parts" : { "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "123" }, "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf6" } } }
{ "name" : "A3", "year" : "2000", "parts" : { "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf6" }, "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "123" } } }
{ "name" : "A3", "year" : "2001", "parts" : { "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf6" }, "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "123" } } }
{ "name" : "A3", "year" : "2002", "parts" : { "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "123" }, "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf6" } } }
{ "name" : "A3", "year" : "2003", "parts" : { "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "557" }, "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf4" } } }
{ "name" : "A3", "year" : "2004", "parts" : { "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "557" }, "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf4" } } }
```

This means that if I want to check which documents have the same nested "parts", I cannot compare them properly.

```
> db.cars.aggregate([
... { $group: {
... _id: { name: "$name", parts: "$parts" },
... models_in_group: { $push: { year:"$year" } },
... } },
... ])
{ "_id" : { "name" : "A3", "parts" : { "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf6" }, "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "123" } } },  "models_in_group" : [ { "year" : "2000" }, { "year" : "2001" } ] }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "A3", "parts" : { "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "557" }, "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf4" } } },  "models_in_group" : [ { "year" : "2003" }, { "year" : "2004" } ] }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "A3", "parts" : { "oil filter" : { "type" : 2, "partno" : "123" }, "air filter" : { "type" : 6, "partno" : "gf6" } } },  "models_in_group" : [ { "year" : "1999" }, { "year" : "2002" } ] }
```

There should only be two groups. So, can mongoimport maintain the specified order of deep nested keys?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to give a specific order, that's because you are importing JSON objects and not a JSON array of objects.

The only way that I think will make the trick is to write a routine that does that for you.